# Is a two-way communication possible over a mirror port?

Tags: switch, packet-sniffer, port-mirroring

I have a network like this:

```
Server -- Router -- PCs
```

I'd like to add a Raspberry to it so that it receives all packets sent from the Server to any PC, analyzes them, and sometimes it also sends some data to some of the PCs.

My idea is to build this network:

```
Server -- Router -- PCs
             |
         Raspberry
```

where the port on which the Server connects to the Router is mirrored onto the one on which the Raspberry is connected to the Router.

Some configuration on the Raspberry and this way it can function as an Analyzer, right?

My question is however, would the other thing also be possible: could the Raspberry send data to the PCs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the switch firmware. For example on an HP 1910 (and its 3Com hardware brothers) monitor port can send and receive frames just as usual, while Cisco switches generally disable all forwarding on destination ports.